# jquery selector not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

This code results in an error at second line ($('boxes div.box'))

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        boxes = $('#boxes div.box');
        images = $('#images > div');
        boxes.each(function (idx) {
            $(this).data('image', images.eq(idx));
        }).hover(
            function () {
                boxes.removeClass('active');
                images.removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
                $(this).data('image').addClass('active');
            });
    });

</script>
```

The error is **"Object doesn't support this property or method"**. The same page works fine in Firefox and Chrome.

Anyone?

Comment: What do your `<script>` tags look like, where you're including jQuery?

Comment: That's an assumption in many cases...if you *knew* the source of the problem why would you be asking?  Script includes cause this, as slight differences will affect *only* IE, never assume!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to declare variables with the `var` keyword, otherwise IE has no idea where they're coming from and so will just break:

```
var boxes = $('#boxes div.box');
var images = $('#images > div');
```

Comment: You're supposed to declare variables that you use for the first time using `var` anyway — I would think IE chokes on trying to use undeclared variables.

Comment: As far as I can tell this works because IE is a lot stricter on things like this. In IE when a script comes across an error it will just stop dead, while in FF and Chrome they manage to intelligently work around it and continue running the script.

Comment: I thought it was because not declaring a variable means that you add the variable as a property to the `window` object... but I'm not sure why the `window` object can't take a jQuery object as a property?