# 'length' is null or not an object? IE 8. Help please

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

Here is the code, any ideas? This works in other browsers, but it's stuck in ie8. Any help will be appreciated .

```
function getRadioValue(radioN)
{
    for(i=0; i<document.kartice_form[radioN].length; i++)
    {
        if (document.kartice_form[radioN][i].checked == true)
            return parseInt(document.kartice_form[radioN][i].value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Re the jQuery tag: there's nothing about this code that uses jQuery.

Comment: could you please paste your HTML code

Comment: @arjuncc - that's not true; IE has no problem with undeclared variables; it just assumes they're global, like all other browsers. And the `i` variable is completely irrelevant to this question. (having said that, the advice to declare `var i;` is good advice even if the reason given is completely wrong).

Comment: A tip, use local variables `var i = 0` , put `var` in front. You have declared global one. In future when strict mode is implemented you'll be punished by the browser for such code

Comment: what is in your document.kartice_form[radioN] element? show the html code

Comment: @SDC  I had faced a problems once with undeclared variable. Thats why I asked like that. LIke this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857941/jquery-selector-not-working-in-ie8 . I just mentioned it. Thats all. And also I have removed my comment

Comment: The usage of `name` attribute to identify HTML elements has been deprecated and obsoleted and forbidden and banned for a decade ago! Please give `id`s for your elements and use `getElementById()`... Also assuming you're using "global" element identification, those names and ids can be found from `window`, not from `document`.

Comment: Suggestion: Create a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A re-written function for you, using jQuery (assuming jQuery is okay, since you included it in your tags):

```
function getRadioValue(radioN) {
    return parseInt($('input[name="+radioN+"]:checked').val());
}
```